# Mongo Connection Count creeping up one per 10 second with mgo driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, connection-leaks

We monitor our mongoDB connection count using this:

http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#GetStats

However, we have been facing a strange connection leak issue where the connectionCount creeps up consistently by 1 more open connection per 10 seconds. (That's regardless whether there is any requests). I can spin up a server in localhost, leave it there, do nothing, the conectionCount will still creep up. Connection count eventually creeps up to a few thousand and it kills the app/db then and we have to restart the app.

This might not be enough information for you to debug. Does anyone have any ideas, connection leaks that you have dealt with in the past. How did you debug it? What are some of the way that I can debug this.

We have tried a few things, we scanned our code base for any code that could open a connection and put counters/debugging statements there, and so far we have found no leak. It is almost like there is a leak in a library somewhere.

This is a bug in a branch that we have been working on and there have been a few hundred commits into it. We have done a diff between this and master and couldn't find why there is a connection leak in this branch.

As an example, there is the dataset that I am referencing:

```
Clusters:      1   
MasterConns:   9936      <-- creeps up 1 per second
SlaveConns:    -7359     <-- why is this negative?
SentOps:       42091780   
ReceivedOps:   38684525   
ReceivedDocs:  39466143   
SocketsAlive:  78        <-- what is the difference between the socket count and the master conns count?
SocketsInUse:  1231   
SocketRefs:    1231
```

MasterConns is the number that creeps up one per 10 second. I am not entirely sure what the other numbers can mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`MasterConns` cannot tell you whether there's a leak or not, because it does not decrease. The field indicates the number of connections made since the last statistics reset, not the number of sockets that are currently in use. The latter is indicated by the `SocketsAlive` field.

To give you some additional relief on the subject, every single test in the mgo suite is wrapped around logic that ensures that statistics show sane values after the test finishes, so that potential leaks don't go unnoticed. That's the main reason why such statistics collection system was introduced.

Then, the reason why you see this number increasing every 10 seconds or so is due to the internal activity that happens to learn the status of the cluster. That said, this behavior was recently changed so that it doesn't establish new connections and instead picks existent sockets from the pool, so I believe you're not using the latest release.

Having `SlaveConns` negative looks like a bug. There's a small edge case about statistics collection for connections made, because we cannot tell whether a given server is a master or a slave before we've talked to it, so there might be an uncovered path. If you still see that behavior after you upgrade, please report the issue and I'll be happy to look at it.

`SocketsInUse` is the number of sockets that are still being referenced by one or more sessions, whether they are alive (the connection is established) or not. `SocketsAlive` is, again, the real number of live TCP connections. The delta between the two indicates that a number of sessions were not closed. This may be okay, if they are still being held in memory by the application and will eventually be closed, or it may be a leak if a `session.Close` operation was missed by the application.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo! Could you please also elaborate the difference between  socketsAlive vs SocketsInUse and SocketRefs? Why is socketAlive less than SocketsInUse?

Comment: Sure, completed the response.